# How do I search a Wikimedia web site for ALL keywords

Tags: search, wikipedia

I have a Wikimedia site that I want to search for both keywords that I type into the search box.

When I go to the `wikipedia.org` site and look at the help it says that I can precede words with a + sign to force them to be present.
http://si.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Searching

When I go to the Wikimedia help page it doesn't mention this usage:
http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Searching

...and the + sign does not force ALL word search on my Wikimedia site.

Is there a way to force search for both words on a Wikimedia site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try AND, this works for most websites.

Comment: Have you tried this? It does not work on WikiMedia sites from what I can tell.

Comment: No I haven't,but it does work on a lot of websites,btw

Answer (score 0):

How about using a [Wikipedia-specific Google searchbox](http://www.google.com/custom?sa=Google+Search&domains=wikipedia.org&sitesearch=wikipedia.org)?

> Search Wikipedia faster with Google
>   search tricks
>
> The default Wikipedia search engine
>   **can be slow and unreliable**. Luckily, alternatives are available,
>   such as a customized Google searchbox,
>   already preset to search Wikipedia

Comment: This site runs on an intranet and is not indexed by Google.